# Adding an item to an array and getting its index

Tags: javascript

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) takes a value and appends it to the referenced array, returning its new length. Is it possible to instead get the index of an item when I append it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract `1` from the length after adding the item to get its index:

```js
const addIndex = (array, item) => array.push(item) - 1

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

addIndex(array, 6)
//=> 5
```